# Asking a question as anonymous

Tags: support

Can I ask a question as anonymous using my account or do I have to login as a guest and use a different e-mail account?

Comment: Thanks. I am not particularly worried about anonymity it is more for formal reasons.

Comment: Reminder: while posting (asking, answering, and commenting) from different accounts (including anonymous accounts) is not actively forbidden, voting or behaving poorly using separate accounts on Stackexchange is forbidden.  Use such accounts wisely and only for good.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Multiple Accounts" Paseman, 2016.12.14.